# Enhance the execution time of data frame column transformation code

Tags: r

I have a data frame having more than a million rows. It has a key column having key values as character. This key column has around 900 distinct values. A number of these values are minor variations of a standard value. Out of these 900 values, approx 175 of them are to be mapped to standard values. The following sample code explains how did I get the mapping done to correct the values. Here "Event 1" value  needs to be replaced by "evt 1":

```
id = c(1:4)
k1 = c("Event 1", "evt 1", "evt 2", "evt 3")
v1 = c(101:104)
df = data.frame(id, k1, v1)
df$k1 = as.character(df$k1)

### map the non-standard values to standard values using named vector approach
mapEvents = c("Event 1" = "evt 1")
vNames = names(mapEvents)

stTime = proc.time()
df$k1 = ifelse(df$k1 %in% vNames, mapEvents[df$k1], df$k1)
proc.time() - stTime
```

This code works ok BUT with a serious performance issue. The ifelse code takes around 9 minutes to complete on my i7 system.

How I make this mapping to execute in fastest possible way? Appreciate the help very much.

Comment: You should investigate the `data.tables` package. There is somewhat of a learning curve, but it speeds up things like this quite a bit.

Comment: Based on @John's recommendation, I solved the above problem with data.table and shared my answer below. But I don't know how to indicate that as an answer. All the other approaches were data specific where as data.table approach is more generic and can be used in various scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the SO question [Update subset of data.table based on join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720923/update-subset-of-data-table-based-on-join), below is the one answer.

```
## convert the mapping vector to a data table
  dtMap = data.table(idMap=names(mapEvents), mappedValue=mapEvents)
  setkey(dtMap, idMap)

  ## convert the data frame to a data table
  dt_df = data.table(df)
  setkey(dt_df, k1)

  ## do the update and convert the data table back to data frame
  dt_df[dtMap[dt_df[k1 %in% dtMap$idMap],nomatch=0],c("k1"):=list(i.mappedValue)]
  df = as.data.frame(dt_df)
```

data.table is just marvelous. Need to explore it and use it more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the 'only' replacement you wish to do is from "Event" to "evt", but for a large number of combinations with different serial numbers, it may more convenient to replace the string only. Without knowing more about your data it's hard to tell though.

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_first_fixed(str = k1, pattern = "Event", replacement = "evt")
# [1] "evt 1" "evt 1" "evt 2" "evt 2" "evt 3" "evt 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df$k1[df$k1 %in% "Event 1"] <- "evt 1"
```

If you have multiple values you need to remap:

```
remap <- list("evt 1" = "Event 1",
              "evt 2" = c('a','b','c'),
              "evt 3" = c('x','y','z'),
              ...etc...)

for(i in seq_along(remap)) {
    w <- which(df$k1 %in% remap[[i]])
    df$k1[w] <- names(remap)[i]
}
```